# How to change values in a section of column based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the values for a section of a column (rows 109 to 140), if they are not equal to 3 different strings.

I'm trying to not iterate, right now I can only seem to do it for one condition only.

```
df.loc[109:140,1] != 'Method' or df.loc[109:140,1] != 'Replicates' or df.loc[109:140,1] != 'StandardDeviation'

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I've tried this:

```
df.loc[109:140,1] != ('Method', 'Replicates', 'StandardDeviation')
```

But it seems to make it an "and" statement.

I'm getting this error a lot:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I've tried using a `|` instead and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# mcve:

# np.random.seed(42)
# df = pd.DataFrame({1: np.random.choice(('asdf', 'Method', 'Replicates', 'StandardDeviation'), 10)})

#                    1
# 0         Replicates
# 1  StandardDeviation
# 2               asdf
# 3         Replicates
# 4         Replicates
# 5  StandardDeviation
# 6               asdf
# 7               asdf
# 8         Replicates
# 9             Method
```

Create a mask with `pd.Series.isin()`

```
mask = df[1].isin(('Method', 'Replicates', 'StandardDeviation'))
```

and use `where` to change a subset of your Series where mask is `False`.

```
df.loc[5:9, 1] = df.loc[5:9, 1].where(mask, 'new better value')
```

result:

```
#                    1
# 0         Replicates
# 1  StandardDeviation
# 2               asdf
# 3         Replicates
# 4         Replicates
# 5  StandardDeviation
# 6   new better value
# 7   new better value
# 8         Replicates
# 9             Method
```

Comment: How would you do this if you wanted it to change a subset of the Series where mask is ```True```?

Comment: You can just negate the mask to achieve that: `df.loc[5:9, 1] = df.loc[5:9, 1].where(~mask, 'new better value')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[109:140]["NAME_OF_COLUMN_1"] = df.apply(lambda row: value1
                                            if row['NAME_OF_COLUMN_1'] not in ['Method', 'Replicates', 'StandardDeviation']
                                            else row['NAME_OF_COLUMN_1'], axis=1)
```

Comment: What is "value1"? Would that be df.loc[109,1]?

Comment: value1 is whatever value you want to use if the value in column 1 is not in that list.  If those values are in other columns in your dataframe, then you can change value1 to row["COLUMN_X"] or row["COLUMN_Y"]

Answer (score 0):

Please, have a look at the [Series.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) function. It does exactly what you want

```
df.loc[109:140,1].isin(['Method', 'Replicates', 'StandardDeviation'])
```